# What is the difference between KL Divergence and merely subtracting entropy measurements?

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy

I'm wondering what the difference between KL divergence and just subtracting one entropy measurement from another is. I can see what the difference is mathematically...but I'm having a hard time grasping what it means. Throughout this I'm thinking of entropy measurements of English text, but I'm not sure that matters.

Consider that you have two models for some random variable X, p (the good model), and q (the less-good model).

If we compute entropy $$H(X) = -\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p(x) \log(p(x)) = let's\,say\,2\,bits\,per\,character$$
and
$$H(X) = -\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} q(x) \log(q(x)) = 3\,bits\,per\,character$$
we can obtain a difference measure simply by subtracting:

$$H_{diff}(p(x),q(x)) = -\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} q(x) \log(q(x)) - -\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p(x) \log(p(x)) = 1\,bit\,per\,character$$

simplified a bit to be analogous in form to a common statement of KL Divergence...
$$H_{diff}(p(x),q(x)) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p(x)\log(p(x)) - q(x)\log(q(x)) = 1\,bit\,per\,character$$

Okay, so that makes a sort of intuitive sense. If we've got 1000 characters then on average for model q we'll see 3000 bits, whereas on average for model p we'll see 2000 bits. Got it, I think?

But we can also use KL divergence, which is very similar:

$$D_\text{KL}(p \parallel q) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p(x) \log\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)$$

Rearrange a bit...

$$D_\text{KL}(p \parallel q) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}} p(x)\log(p(x)) - p(x)\log(q(x)) $$

So, really the only difference between simply taking the difference of the two entropy calculations and KL Divergence is p(x) vs. q(x) in the second term on the right-hand side, which is cross-entropy in the case of KL divergence and regular old entropy in my first example.

I've been thinking about it for a while here and I can't come up with an answer. What, intuitively, is the difference between these two distance measures?

Comment: The difference could clearly be negative, depending on which term was subtracted from the other. But the KL divergence is nonnegative.   Also, if two distributions have the same entropy, then the difference would be zero, even if the distributions are not the same. However, the KL divergence between two distributions is zero if and only if they are the same almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's helpful. You're right that the difference could be negative. In my case I'm looking at two probability distributions, p(x) the good model and q(x) the not so good model, both operating on the same random variable (English text). If one model is always better and I know which one it is, I can always arrange the Hdiff measure to be positive for my purposes.

Comment: KL divergence being zero only if the two distributions are the same is important...but maybe not so important in my case, where one distribution is an approximation of the other? I think any way you slice it these two measures will be very similar in magnitude in my specific case, I'm just trying to make the principled decision.

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but if you compare the distributions using KL divergence, that would be common, but if you take the difference, I believe that would be very uncommon, so that choice would require more justification.

Comment: I appreciate you thinking about it Joe. I'm trying to develop an understanding of how much information about a random variable is in a decoder on the basis of comparing the entropy measurements performed with two different decoders on the same random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious difference pointed out in the comments by @Joe:

I think the key difference is that the KL divergence represents the relative difference between two probability measures (recall that the absolutely continuity property ($p \ll q$) is required for KL divergence to be finite), while the difference you mentioned is just a difference between entropies of two completely different probability spaces, which gives no clue about how much the distributions are close to each other.